# Pyspark - How use a function with two arguments taken from my rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following function that compares two strings of same length and computes their Matching coefficient(similarity between the strings). The function goes as follows:

```
def SMC(str1,str2):
    count = 0
    for i in range (len(str1)):
        if (str1[i]==str2[i]):
            count+=1
    return count/len(str1)
```

Now suppose, I have an RDD as follows:

```
RDD= sc.parallelize([('abc','adc'),('fgh','bch'),('ast','ast')])
```

I want to use my fuction `SMC` to form a new RDD which is formed by the values that the function `SMC` returns when it is applied to each pair. For example when the pair `('abc','adc')` goes in the function `SMC` it returns the value `0.66`. My expected output RDD2 would be as follows:

```
>>> RDD2.collect()
    [0.666,0.333,1.0]
```

How can I write a map function for this and how can I pass the desired arguments to my function. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `map` function like this:

```py
RDD2 = RDD.map(lambda x: SMC(x[0], x[1]))
RDD2.collect()
```

which yields

```
[0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 1.0]
```

Note that for your function to work, I cast the count into a floating number in the return: `return float(count)/len(str1)`